# FFmpeg Android Video cropping speed and perfomance

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-camera2, android-ffmpeg

`FFmpeg` 15 seconds video takes 15 seconds to crop.
How can we reduce this cropping time with command or some other tricks?

I have refereed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000398/ffmpeg-video-cropping-slower) but didn't helped.

**Here is code**

```
final FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(getActivity());
        try {
            ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onStart() {}
                @Override
                public void onFailure() {}
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.i(TAG, "FFMPEG Success ");
                    try {

                        /*Logic for cropping the original video to a square video depending of the                                           orientation of the original video*/

                        //Command for cropping square video
                        String[] cmd = {"-i", "path/source.mp4", "-vf", "scale=720:ih*720/iw, crop="720:720:0:0, "-preset","ultrafast","-strict","experimental","-vcodec","libx264","-preset","ultrafast","path/destination.mp4"};
                        // Execute cropping of video
                        ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

                            @Override
                            public void onStart() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onProgress(String message) {
                                Log.i("Square", "progress : " +message);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(String message) {
                                Log.i("Square", "total fail : " + message);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                                Log.i("Square", "Cropped video created.");

                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onFinish() {
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
                        // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
            // Handle if FFmpeg is not supported by device
        }
```

**Logcat**

```
D/FFmpeg: Running publishing updates method
I/Square: progress : ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
I/Square: progress :   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
I/Square: progress :   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
I/Square: progress :   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
I/Square: progress :   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
I/Square: progress :   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
I/Square: progress :   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
I/Square: progress :   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
I/Square: progress :   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
I/Square: progress :   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
I/Square: progress :   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
I/Square: progress : Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/Content/source.mp4':
I/Square: progress :   Metadata:
I/Square: progress :     major_brand     : mp42
I/Square: progress :     minor_version   : 0
I/Square: progress :     compatible_brands: isommp42
I/Square: progress :     creation_time   : 2016-10-05 05:19:12
I/Square: progress :     com.android.version: 6.0.1
I/Square: progress :   Duration: 00:00:15.91, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6174 kb/s
I/Square: progress :     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 326 kb/s, 1.59 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 15 tbc (default)
I/Square: progress :     Metadata:
I/Square: progress :       rotate          : 90
I/Square: progress :       creation_time   : 2016-10-05 05:19:12
I/Square: progress :       handler_name    : VideoHandle
I/Square: progress :     Side data:
I/Square: progress :       displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
I/Square: progress :     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 8000 Hz, mono, fltp, 12 kb/s (default)
I/Square: progress :     Metadata:
I/Square: progress :       creation_time   : 2016-10-05 05:19:12
I/Square: progress :       handler_name    : SoundHandle
I/Square: progress : [libx264 @ 0xf7544400] using SAR=1/1
I/Square: progress : [libx264 @ 0xf7544400] using cpu capabilities: none!
I/Square: progress : [libx264 @ 0xf7544400] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1
I/Square: progress : [libx264 @ 0xf7544400] 264 - core 148 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
I/Square: progress : [aac @ 0xf7544c00] Too many bits 8832.000000 > 6144 per frame requested, clamping to max
I/Square: progress : Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/Content/destination.mp4':
I/Square: progress :   Metadata:
I/Square: progress :     major_brand     : mp42
I/Square: progress :     minor_version   : 0
I/Square: progress :     compatible_brands: isommp42
I/Square: progress :     com.android.version: 6.0.1
I/Square: progress :     encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
I/Square: progress :     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 638x638 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
I/Square: progress :     Metadata:
I/Square: progress :       handler_name    : VideoHandle
I/Square: progress :       creation_time   : 2016-10-05 05:19:12
I/Square: progress :       encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libx264
I/Square: progress :     Side data:
I/Square: progress :       unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
I/Square: progress :     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 8000 Hz, mono, fltp, 48 kb/s (default)
I/Square: progress :     Metadata:
I/Square: progress :       creation_time   : 2016-10-05 05:19:12
I/Square: progress :       handler_name    : SoundHandle
I/Square: progress :       encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 aac
I/Square: progress : Stream mapping:
I/Square: progress :   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
I/Square: progress :   Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
I/Square: progress : Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
I/Square: progress : frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:05.24 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=10.2x    
I/Square: progress : frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:10.24 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=  10x    
I/Square: progress : frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=      19kB time=00:00:14.84 bitrate=  10.5kbits/s speed=9.73x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8519 fps=205 q=23.0 size=    3734kB time=00:04:43.53 bitrate= 107.9kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=6.84x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8537 fps=203 q=25.0 size=    3734kB time=00:04:44.13 bitrate= 107.7kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=6.77x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8556 fps=201 q=25.0 size=    3735kB time=00:04:44.76 bitrate= 107.4kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed= 6.7x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8575 fps=199 q=25.0 size=    3843kB time=00:04:45.40 bitrate= 110.3kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=6.64x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8594 fps=198 q=25.0 size=    3844kB time=00:04:46.03 bitrate= 110.1kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=6.58x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8614 fps=196 q=25.0 size=    3844kB time=00:04:46.70 bitrate= 109.8kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=6.52x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8633 fps=194 q=25.0 size=    3844kB time=00:04:47.33 bitrate= 109.6kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=6.45x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8652 fps=192 q=25.0 size=    3844kB time=00:04:47.96 bitrate= 109.4kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed= 6.4x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8672 fps=190 q=26.0 size=    3844kB time=00:04:48.63 bitrate= 109.1kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=6.34x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8691 fps=189 q=25.0 size=    3845kB time=00:04:49.26 bitrate= 108.9kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=6.28x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8711 fps=187 q=26.0 size=    3845kB time=00:04:49.93 bitrate= 108.6kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=6.23x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8731 fps=185 q=26.0 size=    3845kB time=00:04:50.60 bitrate= 108.4kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=6.17x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8750 fps=184 q=26.0 size=    3845kB time=00:04:51.23 bitrate= 108.2kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=6.12x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8770 fps=182 q=26.0 size=    3846kB time=00:04:51.90 bitrate= 107.9kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=6.07x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8791 fps=181 q=26.0 size=    3846kB time=00:04:52.60 bitrate= 107.7kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=6.02x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8811 fps=179 q=26.0 size=    3846kB time=00:04:53.26 bitrate= 107.4kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=5.97x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8831 fps=178 q=26.0 size=    3971kB time=00:04:53.93 bitrate= 110.7kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=5.92x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8851 fps=177 q=26.0 size=    4214kB time=00:04:54.60 bitrate= 117.2kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=5.88x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8871 fps=175 q=25.0 size=    4451kB time=00:04:55.26 bitrate= 123.5kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=5.83x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8891 fps=174 q=26.0 size=    4705kB time=00:04:55.93 bitrate= 130.2kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=5.78x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8911 fps=172 q=26.0 size=    4963kB time=00:04:56.60 bitrate= 137.1kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=5.74x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8932 fps=171 q=26.0 size=    5226kB time=00:04:57.30 bitrate= 144.0kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed= 5.7x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8952 fps=170 q=26.0 size=    5475kB time=00:04:57.96 bitrate= 150.5kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=5.65x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8972 fps=169 q=26.0 size=    5730kB time=00:04:58.63 bitrate= 157.2kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=5.61x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8992 fps=167 q=26.0 size=    5970kB time=00:04:59.30 bitrate= 163.4kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=5.57x    
I/Square: progress : frame= 8993 fps=167 q=-1.0 Lsize=    9456kB time=00:04:59.76 bitrate= 258.4kbits/s dup=8516 drop=0 speed=5.56x    
I/Square: progress : video:9350kB audio:68kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.404826%
I/Square: progress : [libx264 @ 0xf7544400] frame I:36    Avg QP:10.64  size:107101
I/Square: progress : [libx264 @ 0xf7544400] frame P:8957  Avg QP:13.80  size:   638
I/Square: progress : [libx264 @ 0xf7544400] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
I/Square: progress : [libx264 @ 0xf7544400] mb P  I16..4:  0.4%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  4.3%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:95.3%
I/Square: progress : [libx264 @ 0xf7544400] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 78.5% 24.5% 12.4% inter: 2.6% 0.2% 0.0%
I/Square: progress : [libx264 @ 0xf7544400] i16 v,h,dc,p: 28% 12% 42% 18%
I/Square: progress : [libx264 @ 0xf7544400] i8c dc,h,v,p: 59% 15% 22%  4%
I/Square: progress : [libx264 @ 0xf7544400] kb/s:255.50
I/Square: progress : [aac @ 0xf7544c00] Qavg: 65536.000
I/Square: Cropped video created.
I/Square: finished
```

Comment: Which ffmpeg demo are you referring ?

Comment: @Nisarg check [this](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java)

Comment: Try demo from [this](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html), its quite updated one.

Comment: Now that I can see your console output I realize this is a duplicate question. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33507589/1109017).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard What should i do, should i remove `libx264` from command?

Comment: Probably not unless you don't want H.264 video. You should re-compile `x264` and `ffmpeg` as mentioned in the answer, and investigate decoding via Mediacodec. Otherwise there isn't much else you can do if you want to use `ffmpeg`.